# how to get nearest tenth of a double

Tags: java, math

I want to round up double number in java such that it converts to it's nearest tenth like below..

```
0.1--->0.1
0.3--->1
1----->1
1.5---->10
92---->100
4.0E8-->1.0E9
etc
```

How can I do it
Actually my intention is to set Y-axis on chart, if max value is 0.1 then num_ spacing will set to .01 if it is .3 then convert to 1 then set num_ spacing to .1 and so on

Comment: 0.1--->0.1
But 0.3--->1
Why this difference ?

Comment: because 0.1 is 1/10, he wants to reach the next tenth value, not the logical rounding.

Comment: Do you want a function or what ?

Comment: The rounding sequence looks weird. `|0.3 - 0.1| < |0.3 - 1|`. Why is 0.3 rounded to 1?

Comment: actually it is to set Y-axis on chart, if max value if 0.1 then num_ spacing will set to .01 if it is .3 then convert to 1 then set num_ spacing to .1 and so on

Comment: Doubles can't represent all tenths precisely. You can round to the nearest double of the nearest tenth though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try translating this into your language, I've written it in Matlab but it ought to be obvious

```
10^ceil(log10(x))
```

Of course, this will only work if `x` is positive.

Comment: In Java, it's: `Math.pow(Math.ceil(Math.log10(x)), 10)`

Comment: Actually the exponent is the second argument: `Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(x)));`

Comment: To round down, replace `ceil` with `floor`.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look..

```
              double a = 120.1;
    double last_digit_rem = 10 - (a % 10);
    System.out.println(a+last_digit_rem);
```

It will work for negative numbers also...

Comment: I think the result should be 1000 in this case not 130

Comment: No... It is 0.09999999999999432, so, 10-(a%10) will be 9.900000000000006, final result would be 130.0